# Raspberry pi LIRC will not allow IR receiving

Tags: raspberry-pi, lirc

I Have connected both IR receiver and transmitter to my system.
I followed a certain tutorial which enabled the system to use the IR receiver. But, when I connected my transmitter and Installed LIRC on my system, it stopped being able to receive data (I checked using evtest), I checked and everything seems fine, the LED on the receiver lights up when IR code is received. How can I fix it? I guess that something in the configuration went wrong so I'll show the files here. Thanks for helping.

lirc_option.conf file:
`driver = default device = /dev/lirc0`

/boot/config.txt file:
`dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17 dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=22`

/etc/modules file:
`lirc_dev lirc_rpi gpio_out_pin=22`

I only included the things I've changes, other than that everything is default.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the solution, just remove everything I added to the /etc/modules file and it works fine.